# Nav bar with 'float: left;' & 'float: right;'

Tags: html, css

I want my nav bar to have the navigation buttons on the left & my signup/login to the right. I've managed to have a main nav bar, and a separated navbar for the login/signup, but that messes with my code.

I've tried to do something with the ':last-child' but it doesn't seem to work...

```css
.nav-wrapper ul {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 36px;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 18px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.24px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden">
  <label for="nav" class="nav-btn">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
                    </label>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#" class="name">"logo"</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="collections.php">Collections</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack Overflow :) Why do you have some PHP in your HTML? Can you edit the snippet to have a clean [MCVE]?

Comment: `float` layouts are a technique of the past with `grid` and `flexbox` available.

Comment: Try to remove `float: left;`

Comment: Use floats not the last-child pseudo. Have a main div float left then a float left for the left inside content div #1 then float right for div #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my opinion you can have a header element (the topbar), with two nav inside, each with its own alignment

```
<header class="topbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#" class="mylogo">My logo</a>
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="collections.php">Collections</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="user">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

and then

```
header.topbar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
nav.navigation {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
nav.user {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox on your `ul` element and move its last child element to the right by applying `margin-left: auto` to it (no floats needed in this case):

```css
.nav-wrapper ul {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 36px;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 18px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.24px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav" class="hidden">
  <label for="nav" class="nav-btn">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
                    </label>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#" class="name">"logo"</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="collections.php">Collections</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>'
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried it, but I have the same problem if I had simply removed the float left. It gives some kind of weird effect...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code, it will work if you remove `float: left;` from `.nav-wrapper ul`.

In my opinion, it is more intuitive to use CSS grid, and divide your `ul` into two logical units (main `ul` for the left side, and secondary `ul` for the right side):

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

.nav-wrapper ul.list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 36px;
}

.nav-wrapper ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1.24px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="list list-main">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="collections.php">Collections</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list list-secondary">
        <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```